# Does visual studio code download to a Chromebook or do I have to have a PC?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, chromebook

Does visual studio code download to a Chromebook or do I have to have a PC?

I am teaching my middle school students Python using codehs.com and then have them use it to program Lego EV3 Robots.

The problem I have is that the Visual Studio Code program with Python extension doesn't want to load to a Chromebook.  Do I need a PC or can it be Chromebook friendly?

Steve
Middle School in Oregon

Comment: Stack Overflow is perhaps not the best forum for this question (imho it is more for questions about writing code rather than platform issues). A quick google eg: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/12/03/chromebook-get-started suggests it is at least possible. I hope you find a solution as getting kids coding is very worthwhile and as an AFOL I am firmly on your side!

Comment: The link I supplied suggests there is a certain amount of preparation required on the Chromebook (eg enabling Linux support) which is necessary before you can install VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can download Visual Studio Code on [supported Chromebooks](https://www.reddit.com/r/Crostini/wiki/getstarted/crostini-enabled-devices/) using Crostini (Linux Support for Chrome OS).

Here's how:

1. Enable Linux Development Environment by going in Chrome OS Settings, scrolling to the `Developers` section, and clicking `Linux Development Environment: Turn On`.
2. Wait for the Linux VM to download. When it finishes, the Terminal app will open. If necessary, click `penguin` to open the terminal.
3. Type the following two commands, each followed by pressing the enter key to update the Linux VM:

```
sudo apt update -y;
sudo apt upgrade -y;
```

4. Navigate to this page: https://code.visualstudio.com/download, and choose the `.deb` option (if you have an ARM CPU chromebook, choose the ARM option). Save the file `.deb` into the `Linux` folder which is now in your Files.
5. Run the following command, replacing FILENAME.deb with the actual name of the file you just downloaded: `sudo apt install -y ./FILENAME.deb`
6. Visual Studio Code should now be installed. If you look in the launcher, there will be a folder called `Linux apps`. Inside, there should be VS Code.